# GAS "IO Error" when using JDBC, but only sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script

In the past week, I've started to get an "IO error" when using JDBC to query an external database from several different Google Apps Scripts.

For instance, one of the scripts runs daily on a time-based trigger, and it had been running successfully from early in 2018 until this morning, when it failed with an "IO error." Other now-problematic scripts have had similar performance in the past -- the earliest problems started around the end of December. (See script examples below.)

The failure point is when the script tries to execute a query statement. The connection to the DB opens just fine, and a statement is successfully created. It's when the script tries to run the executeQuery method that it fails.

Here's what I know:

1. I know my SQL is solid -- these are queries that have been workhorses up until recently, and I can run them successfully outside of Google Apps Script.
2. This is definitely not a "IO error when deserializing continuation" error. The error message is coming from GAS, and it just says "IO error." That's all -- no additional information.
3. I have countless scripts that regularly access this particular database successfully, as well as the same particular data views within the DB. Only a handful have recently become issues.
4. I'm using the V8 runtime environment for both successful and unsuccessful scripts.
5. I've tried establishing the query itself as a string variable before using it with the JDBC statement, as well as putting the query directly in the statement. It doesn't make a difference.

Here's a script that works:

```
function acs() {
  var data;
  try {
  var credentials = SCLSNJ.getCARLAdHocCredentials();
  var url = credentials.dbUrl;
  var username = credentials.username;
  var password = credentials.password;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var acsSQL = 'SELECT COUNT(patronid) FROM patron_v WHERE jts.todate(sactdate) > sysdate - 365 AND bty <> 12';
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(acsSQL);
  while (results.next()) {
    data = results.getString(1);
  }
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  } catch(err) {
    data = err;
  } finally {
  return data;
  }
}
```

And here's a script that doesn't work:

```
function acps() {
  var data;
  try {
  var credentials = SCLSNJ.getCARLAdHocCredentials();
  var url = credentials.dbUrl;
  var username = credentials.username;
  var password = credentials.password;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var acpsSQL = 'SELECT COUNT(patronid) FROM patron_v WHERE jts.todate(actdate) > sysdate - 365 AND jts.todate(sactdate) > sysdate - 365 AND bty <> 12';
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(acpsSQL);
  while (results.next()) {
    data = results.getString(1);
  }
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  } catch(err) {
    data = err;
  } finally {
  return data;
  }
}
```

(NOTE: Both are using a library to get credentials for my DB.)

The SQL for these two is almost exactly the same, and they're running against a table with 100,000-ish rows representing customers, so it's not like it's querying millions of transactional records. The only difference between these two queries -- which even happen to run from within the same GAS project as each other -- is that the second one includes an additional WHERE clause. That's it. The first one works, and the second returns the IO error at `var results = stmt.executeQuery(acpsSQL);`

Help!

**EDITED to add log example**

One of my regular time-triggered daily scripts errored this morning, and here's what the Stackdriver logs have to say:

```
{
  "insertId": "-bmyy6cfcuu7xm",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "context": {
      "reportLocation": {
        "lineNumber": 44,
        "filePath": "Code",
        "functionName": "getCircTransactions"
      }
    },
    "message": "Exception: IO Error\n    at getCircTransactions(Code:44:22)",
    "serviceContext": {
      "service": "AKfycbzNeA-RMlnYzXNhfL1XO1voPYNM34p1eHRaCPG1Uiph"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "app_script_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "getCircTransactions",
      "project_id": "project-id-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "invocation_type": "unknown"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-01-07T06:56:23.959Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "logName": "projects/project-id-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-07T06:56:24.177318594Z"
}
```

**EDITED again to add**
In the past week, a third script (which is almost identical to the acs() script above, with the exception of a different parameter), has run without error *most* days, but not all:

Thu 1/7 - success
Fri 1/8 - success
Sat 1/9 - success
Sun 1/10 - success
Mon 1/11 - IO Error at `statement.executeQuery()`
Tue 1/12 - IO Error at `statement.executeQuery()`
Wed 1/13 - success

Here's that function:

```
function acp() {
  var data;
  try {
  var credentials = SCLSNJ.getCARLAdHocCredentials();
  var url = credentials.dbUrl;
  var username = credentials.username;
  var password = credentials.password;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var acpsSQL = 'SELECT COUNT(patronid) FROM patron_v WHERE jts.todate(actdate) > sysdate - 365 AND bty <> 12';
  var results = stmt.executeQuery(acpsSQL);
  while (results.next()) {
    data = results.getString(1);
  }
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  } catch(err) {
    data = err;
  } finally {
  return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs in this situation? Perhaps a more detailed message regarding this is being displayed. Also, how often are you getting the error? @LynnHoffman

Comment: @ale13 For the most part it seems as though once a script starts generating this error, it always generates this error. (There was an exception: when I was testing yesterday with the `acps()` function above, it *did* run manually once, but then it went back to erroring out again, and the error happened this morning, too.)

Log info above...

Comment: How does the `getCircTransactions` function look like? From the error message it looks like the error occurs there.

Comment: There are actually more subfunctions that run off the same trigger than just the two I put in my question, including getCircTransactions(), some of which work and some of which don't. The error point in each one is `statement.executeQuery(sql)`.

Comment: Did you whitelist the IP ranges from the database? You might want to check this link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#other_databases).

Comment: Yes, the IPs have been whitelisted. As I mentioned above, there are other scripts running against the same database without issue.

Comment: Since the issue you are describing seems to be related to this particular script, it might be best to contact Google Workspace Support [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).